# using describe() with weights

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do some basic summary statistics on a non-binary variable with weights. I have an earnings data and after I use `groupby()` by demographic groups, I want to do something like `describe()`, but with weights.

In [Using describe() with weighted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689099/using-describe-with-weighted-data) and [pandas: groupby and variable weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295596/pandas-groupby-and-variable-weights), the OPs asked very similar questions, but the answers have been insufficient. In my case I want the percentile distribution including the median so multiplying the variable of interest with the weights won't work.

Given how much of data analysis is done with weights, I find it difficult to believe there is no easy way to work with weights and want to try my luck here!

Comment: I think there is still not a great answer to this, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926940/creating-a-partial-sas-proc-summary-replacement-in-python-pandas/29927921#29927921